# How to access the "Browse Image to be Linked" dropdown from an Image Texture node using python?

Tags: python, node-editor

I am trying to access the "Browse Image" dropdown from an Image Texture node using python:

[image]

That is, I want to be able to draw this dropdown to a panel, so that it can be accessed and the image for the node can be set from the panel.

Is there a specific property associated with the Image Texture node that I can reference to do this?

i.e. something along the lines of:

```
row.prop(img_tex_node, 'some_property')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I answered my own question.

All I needed was this:

```
row.prop(img_tex_node, "image")
```

Simple!